# mongodb get data from two collections after version 2.6.5

Tags: mysql, mongodb, socket.io, chat, mongodb-query

**In Mongodb 2.6.5** any way to map two collections?

if consider Following example is there any way to map both **chat_messages** and **users** collection
where **chat_messages.sender_id** and **chat_messages.receiver_id** should refer **users.UserID**.

when i find mongodb i wont names and few details from users table too.

```
db.chat_messages.insert(
   { 
   sender_id:"9190XXXXXXXXX",
receiver_id:"918866132614",
message:"hi t->p",
msgType:"Text"
   }
   )

   db.chat_messages.insert(
   { 
   receiver_id:"9190XXXXXXXXX",
receiver_id:"918866132614",
message:"hi p->t",
msgType:"Text"
   }
   )


db.users.insert(
   { 
   fname: "x",
   lname: "y" ,
    wi_Id:"Tejas005",
    UserID:"9190XXXXXXXXX"
   }
)

db.users.insert(
   { 
   fname: "y",
   lname: "z" ,
    wi_Id:"p1nt0z",
    UserID:"9180XXXXXXXXX"
   }

)
```

is mangoDb is good approach for chatting backend design ?
Right now i have used **Mysql** and **SOCKET.io**,
but after few reads i found **mongodb** is fast in performance than mysql is it true?.
What Could be the best approach for chatting backend with local storage with **socket.io**.

i know this is only the place i can get best suggestion about usage and problems. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As up to now (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/), you cannot join 2 collections in mongodb.

Comment: Than any idea now what could be the option ?

Comment: You have 2 options: put all that is needed into one collection or put them in different collections and use 2 request from your client, then combine responses in code

Comment: But for chatting backend this is not good options to use 2 request from client and combining two collection is also not good idea because name and user image all this things may change with time period so hard to track updated info every time.

Comment: mongodb is a document storage. It pushes you to a design where all required information is combined into one document, in your case, include fname and lname into "chat" document. End if user changes his/her name, you will either update ALL affected documents, or leave that inconsistency there (no one needs yesterdays chat log :) ).

Comment: What is wi_ID? I hope it is not a password :)

Comment: Your idea is smilier what i think. Its good to update all data need to push after getter than user's last seen :)  and wi_id is pKey not password &#128521;